# How to load javascript file by using a layout file

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

Here in below code i am trying to load captcha.js file but its not loading.

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout

```
<reference name="product.info">         
    <block type="questionanswer/questionanswer" name="product.questionanswer" as="questionanswerAs" template="questionanswer/form.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Ask A Question</value></action>
        <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
            </reference>
            <action method="setFormId"><formId>vendor_form</formId></action>
            <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
            <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
        </block>    
    </block>    
</reference>
```

and in custom module config.xml file

```
<default>
    <captcha>
        <frontend>
            <areas>
                <vendor_form>
                    <label>Question_Answer Page</label>
                </vendor_form>
            </areas>
        </frontend>
    </captcha>
    <customer>
        <captcha>
            <always_for>
                <vendor_form>1</vendor_form>
            </always_for>
        </captcha>
    </customer>
</default>
```

> and in phtml file

```
<div class="field">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('captcha'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> layout.xml

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/captcha.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">         
        <block type="questionanswer/questionanswer" name="product.questionanswer" as="questionanswerAs" template="questionanswer/form.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Ask A Question</value></action>
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>vendor_form</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>    
        </block>    
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

You js file should be in : `magentoRoot/js/mage/captcha.js`

Comment: not working i tried your way also

Comment: Look my update..

Comment: actually we have used custom captcha code in contact us page there it is working fine it may be this problems due to 2 times this same code is there

Answer (score 0):

Find the below example xml code for load captcha JS file in contact us page.

```
Please note that here i have used contact us page, so you have to change according to your page or layout. 
    <contacts_index_index>
                <reference name="contactForm">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
                        <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                            <reference name="head">
                                <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                            </reference>
                            <action method="setFormId"><formid>contacts</formid></action>
                            <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                            <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```